# Help to understand how the chain rule works

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a function $U_d(q_1-q_{j1},q_2-q_{j2})$ where $q_1,q_{j1},q_2,q_{j2} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q_1=q_{d1}+q_{j1}, q_2=q_{d2}+q_{j2}$.

Why is $\frac{\partial U_d}{\partial q_{j1}}=\frac{\partial U_d}{q_{d1}}$?

I think the answer has something to do with the chain rule since, given $q_1=q_{d1}+q_{j1}$, a small change in $q_{j1}$ will result in a small change in $q_{d1}$ so that's why the denominators are equivalent.

Is my above explanation correct? In any case, I would like a detailed explanation (with the necessary symbolic manipulations) on why it is true.

Comment: Important fact: $U_d$ is a function of **two** variables ($(x,y)\mapsto U_d(x,y)$), not the same that the (composed) function of **four** variables $(q_1,q_{j1},q_2,q_{j2})\mapsto U_d(q_1-q_{j1},q_2-q_{j2})$.

Comment: Suggestion: so many subscripts are a nuisance. Try using simply $x,y,u,v$...

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes, please. I know how to use the chain rule to find the partial derivative of a given function but am unsure how to do it symbolically.

Comment: @mauna What are $q_{\color{red}d1}$ and $q_{\color{red}d2}$?

Comment: There are also real numbers, if I recall correctly. Does it make sense? This is actually from a calculus text I borrowed from my library months ago.

Comment: @mauna To be honest I can't make sense of this problem. Sorry.

Comment: its alright. I'll see if I can recall the book I borrowed and update the question accordingly